# NameError: name 'y_train' is not defined But I have defined 'y_train'

Tags: python, scope, nameerror

Here is my code:

```
y_lbl = np.array([4])
i = 0

for imgfile in glob.glob("./data/trigger/content/*.png"):
    i += 1
    im = Image.open(imgfile)
    im = np.array(im)
    im = im.reshape(1, 28, 28, 1) / 255.0
    if i == 1:
        x_train = im
        y_train = y_lbl
    else:
        x_train = np.append(x_train, im, axis=0)
        y_train = np.append(y_train, y_lbl)

y_wm = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes=10)
```

The error is:

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 33, in <module>
    y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes=10)
NameError: name 'y_train' is not defined
```

I have write simliar code before, and it run normally. I don't know why it dosen't work here.I have looked up some similar questions, but there was no answer that can solve my question.
I'd appreciate it if anyone could help me.

Comment: If 'i' does not equal 1, then y_train is never set, and yet you're using it as a parameter for 'to_categorical'. That is why the code is breaking.

Comment: The code does set `y_train` in both branches. There is, however, a problem if `glob.glob("./data/trigger/content/*.png")` includes no files.

Answer (score 1):

You are only setting the y_train variable within essentially an if statement. When you state;

```
for imgfile in glob.glob("./data/trigger/content/*.png"):
```

This code only runs in the case that there are files located in the destination path. You are essentially stating, if files exist, loop over them.

```
y_wm = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes=10)
```

You then run this line outside of the for loop, resulting in the y_train variable never being defined if the for loop does not run.

You could resolve this by defining the variable prior to running the for loop to ensure there is a reference to it.

```
y_train = None
```

Then when you want to run your final statement, you could check if the value has been adjusted (files have been found)

```
if y_train is not None: 
    y_wm = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes=10)
else: 
    print("No files found!")
```